# Redirect a asp page clicking on flash button

Tags: flash

I am new to flash..i need a code which redirects to a asp page on clicking a flash button..please tell me where i have to write that code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you are writing Actionsscript 2 or 3. And also there are some different ways to do it but here is my recommendation for you:

Select your button and set instance name e.g "myButton" in properties panel.
In frame 1 in the main timeline enter:

```
// AS3
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myButtonFunction);
function myButtonFunction(event: MouseEvent) {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com");
    navigateToURL(request);
}
```

```
// AS2
myButton.onRelease = function() {
    getURL("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scoll to end of timeline where u have stop(). Replace with:

```
getURL("http://URL_HERE");
```